# Why is my copy constructor deleted?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, ostream, ostringstream

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>

using std::string;
using std::ostream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef std::basic_ostringstream<char> ostringstream;

class Format { //error1
    const char* str;
    ostream& os;
    int index;
    ostringstream savePrint;
public:
    Format(const char* str, ostream& os) :
            str(str), os(os), index(0) {
    }

    ~Format() {
        os << savePrint.str();
    }

    template<class T>
    Format& operator<<(const T& toPrint) {
        while (index < strlen(str) && str[index] != '%') {
            savePrint << str[index++];
        }
        if (index == strlen(str)) {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        assert(str[index] == '%');
        savePrint << toPrint;
        index++;
        return *this;
    }

};

class TempFormat {
    const char* str;
public:
    TempFormat(const char* str) :
            str(str) {
    }
    friend Format operator<<(ostream& os, TempFormat& f) {
        return Format(f.str, os); //error2
    }
};

TempFormat format(const char* str) {
    return TempFormat(str);
}

int main() {
    int year = 2018;
    string hello = "Hello";
    cout << format("% world! The year is %\n") << hello << year; // error3
}
```

I get the following errors:

> use of deleted function 'std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_ostringstream(const std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]'

And:

> use of deleted function 'Format::Format(const Format&)'

And:

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'TempFormat&' from an rvalue of type 'TempFormat'

Can someone explain me why I get these errors and how can I fix them?

Note: I want by this code to implement version of `printf` (with the connection of the `%`).

Comment: Why is not clear what I asking? I mentioned exactly what is my problem.

Comment: The title could be a lot more informative

Comment: As an aside, you should consider using `std::string` for the `str` member here, so that you aren't constantly calling `strlen`, and you can `str.find('%')`

Comment: @lhay86 Seems fine to me.

Comment: @PaulSanders the title was originally "How can I fix these erros?"

Comment: @lhay86 Ah right, sorry, missed that.  Yes, much better.

Comment: @lhay86 Sorry, pesky hypersensitive phone keyboard. It's feeling a bit hormonal I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixes:

```
#include <sstream> // defines std::basic_ostringstream

// ...

    // basic_ostringstream is movable but no copyable.
    // Make Format moveable.
    Format(Format&&) = default;

// ...

    // Cannot bind a reference to a temporary.
    // R-value reference is required here.
    friend Format operator<<(ostream& os, TempFormat&& f)
```

Comment: Thank you. It's fix the errors. Can you explain please  what was the problem?

Comment: @Software_t Added comments for you.

Comment: Ok, so how `&&` allows to get a reference to a temporary? it's not also reference `&&` ? In fact, I don't understand the using in `&&` , what is the meaning of this?

Comment: @Software_t `TempFormat&&` is an r-value reference here. Read up https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: @Caleth `return Format(f.str, os)` requires either copy constructor or move constructor (before C++17). Try compiling without that fix.

Comment: @Caleth It won't compile if `operator=` is used. The user will need to provide it.

Comment: No, I mean having defined `Format::Format(Format&&)`, you [should define the other 4](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @Caleth Declaring `Format(Format&&)` deletes copy constructor and assignment and makes move assignment not declared. This is exactly what is needed here.